# Installing a seed cipher for ssl use in erlang on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, erlang, encryption, seed

I am curious as to why this code is not working. I think it is because I am missing a certain library that provides the seed or possibly rand commands.

This is my error message

> {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{ssl,seed,[<<256 bytes>>],[]},{egs,start,0,[{file,"src/egs.erl"},{line,49}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

This is the line in the .erl

> ssl:seed(crypto:rand_bytes(256)),

If the problem is library related please tell me where I can get seed or rand. If I can install them via the command line "sudo apt-get install ...." that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out crypto does the work in the newer versions of Erlang. So I just deleted the line and recompiled and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

what version of Erlang you use? In modern Erlang there are no "seed" method in "ssl" module. Do you start ssl application before? (`ssl:start().`)

Comment: I am using Erlang R16B,in the command line i call "-boot start_sasl" this is the code in that file                   {release, {"OTP  APN 181 01","%SYS_VSN%"}, {erts, "%ERTS_VSN%"},
 [{kernel,"%KERNEL_VSN%"},
  {stdlib,"%STDLIB_VSN%"},
  {sasl, "%SASL_VSN%"}]}.                                        How do I get the new version of Erlang to start the ssl?

Comment: How do I update the ssl:seed code for the new Erlang version?